# Find element and re-use it later capybara cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a question and it could be very straight forward to sort out.

I'm looking to write a test that will look within an element on page, store the value or text within that element so that it can be used later.

Example:

Within this css path "#clickable-rows > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)`" is a value that I'd like to extract so that I can use it later

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're just looking for [`#text`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#text-instance_method) right?

```
element_css_locator = "#clickable-rows > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)"

# save text of element
element_text = page.find(element_css_locator).text

# later on assert:
page.find(element_css_locator).should have_content element_text 
# or
page.should have_selector(element_css_locator, :text => element_text)
```

It's usually best to find the element both times rather than hanging onto the capybara element instance.

Comment: Excellent thank you, where I was going wrong was inputting .value at the end instead of .text